# Swift JSONDecoder can't decode valid JSON with escape characters

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

In playgrounds, the following code produces an error:

```
import Foundation

struct Model: Codable {

  let textBody: String

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case textBody = "TextBody"
  }
}

let json = """
          {
            "TextBody": "First Line\n\nLastLine"
          }
          """.data(using: .utf8)!


let model = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Model.self, from: json)
```

Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unescaped control character around character 27." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unescaped control character around character 27.}))): file MyPlayground.playground, line 19

The JSON above is perfectly valid according to JSONLint. So what gives?

Update:

I need a solution that will handle data returned from an API. Here is something I came up with so far, but it's gross...

```
if let data = data,
        let dataStr = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8),
        let cleanData = dataStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "", options: .regularExpression).data(using: .utf8)
      {

        do {

          let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.Response.self, from: cleanData)

          completion(.success(response))

        } catch (let error) {

          print(error.localizedDescription)

          completion(.failure(ApiError.decoding))

        }

      }
```

Answer (score 8):

Your `json` in your playground is represented incorrectly. It is constructed from a string literal with the `\n` in it. But that is being replaced newline characters in your string before it’s converted to a `Data`. But a newline is not permitted within JSON string. You need the two separate characters, namely `\` followed by `n` in your string within the JSON. You can do that by escaping the `\` with another `\`, e.g.:

```
let json = """
    {
        "TextBody": "First Line\\n\\nLastLine"
    }
    """.data(using: .utf8)!
```

Or, alternatively, in Swift 5 and later, you can use extended string delimiters, such as:

```
let json = #"""
    {
        "TextBody": "First Line\n\nLastLine"
    }
    """#.data(using: .utf8)!
```

Or:

```
let json = #"{"TextBody": "First Line\n\nLastLine"}"#
    .data(using: .utf8)!
```

---

I’d be very surprised if your web service was returning a JSON with newline characters (`0x0a`) within its string values, rather than `\` character followed by `n` character. That would only happen if some inexperienced back-end developer was manually building JSON rather than using functions that do this properly.

You say that you’re seeing `\n` in Postman. That suggests that your server response is correct, that there are two characters, `\` followed by `n`, within the string. For example, here is a web service that echoed my input back and this JSON is well formed with `\` followed by `n`:

[image]

If your output looks like the above, then your JSON is valid and the problem in your code snippet above is merely a manifestation of how you represented this JSON in a string literal in Swift code in your playground.

You only need to worry if you see `"First line` on one line in this Postman “raw” view and see `Lastline"` on the next line (presumably with no \n).

Bottom line, we should ignore the error in your playground. Parse your actual server response (not cutting-and-copying the JSON into code, or at least not without those extended string literals). Focus on what errors, if any, you get when you parse the actual server response. I wager that if you run your parser on your actual server response, you won’t get this “Unescaped control character” error.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, I've updated my post above with some requirements for a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have no control over the server. The actual raw responses as seen in Postman contain string values with `\n` inside of them.

Comment: Running into the issue in my actual implementation is what prompted me to experiment in a Playground. I got the same error in my original implementation. Once I added the string replacement function above, the issue seems to be resolved although I consider it a gross workaround.

Comment: It is. If that fixed it, your server implementation is plain broken and you should open a ticket to get it fixed.